# Swift / Set a white background on back button on navigation bar

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar

After a lot of research, i have to resign...

I'm working on Xcode7, and swift.

I have a transparent navigation bar, so when i'm scrolling on the viewcontroller (a map), i would like the back button be more visible, so with a white opaque background.

[image]

Any idea to perform that ?

Maybe, just to insert an image as back button.

Answer (score 0):

In your main.storyboard file, click anywhere in the storyboard that is not a viewcontroller, so in the white space. Then in the file inspector, there is property Global Tint that will change the back bar text color. I've looked around for other ways to change it, such as changing the back buttons text color programmatically, and none seem to work. Hope that helps.